# Mea [linguae?] culpa

Tags: translation-check

Is the following phrase: “*Mea [linguae?] culpa*” gramatically correct? It should mean “*My linguistic/lingual fault*”.

I know that just “mea culpa” means “my fault”.

I know that “mea maxima culpa” is correct, so an adjective in the middle is OK. But I'm not sure, what form of the adjective should I use. “Lingua”? “Linguae”?

The phrase will be a header and it means something like: “I've made some mistakes such as choosing wrong words, I admit it” (ironically) and the whole text is about avoiding them.

Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is, you're trying to translate an English pun: "my fault" and "linguistic fault" use two different meanings of the word "fault" - the first means "I'm responsible, guilty", the latter doesn't imply any guilt, being a synonym for "speech error". ***culpa*** only means "blame, guilt, failure", but cannot mean "error", so *linguae culpa* ends up meaning "the tongue's to blame".

The Latin word that has the double meaning of the English is *peccāre, **peccātum*** - it can mean "error, misdeed" as well as "offence, sin". To admit guilt you use the perfect ***peccāvī,*** not the participle; ***linguā** peccāvī* means exactly the same as "погрешил языком" in Rssian, something like "my sin is that my tongue failed me". But to refer to language you need to use words like ***verbīs*** "with (my choice of) words" or ***sermōne*** "with speech".

Using *culpa* to assign a more direct blame to your tongue you'd say *meae linguae culpa* "it's my tongue's fault", but it's impossible to assign blame to yourself (*mea*) and to your tongue (*linguae*) at the same time without using a conjunction (*culpa mea meae**que** linguae* "the blame is mine and my tongue's"); to keep the modifier phrase before the noun seems to require the genitive pronoun instead of the possessive (***meī*** *meae**que** linguae culpa*). Some might say that this breaks the original syntax and the pun.

- Notice the since you're blaming the faulty result of speech production on the faultiness of your tongue organ by playful metonymy, it can only be used of *oral* speech, and this isn't an established expression either. However, Latin has an established idiomatic metonymy of a tool for the *written* result, and that's of course ***stylus.*** This makes *meī stylī culpa* a workable expression for careless use of language in the written medium, supported by at least [one precedent](https://books.google.com/books?id=c3RmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22styli%20culpa%22) (here contrasted precisely with intentional use due to holding false beliefs).
- Latin has no single word for "a peculiar use of language whether spoken or written, style", and when not referring to the speech organ, *mea lingua* can only mean "my native system of communication" - and here we don't want to blame the entire language, just our inappropriate use of it.
- But you **can** use *mea Latīnitās* to mean "the use of Latin particular to me, my Latinity". However, this is limited to *tās*-nouns for languages, which apart from *Graecitās* didn't find much use.

There's a single word for inappropriate use of words in Latin, ***soloecismus.*** But the bottom line is that you need a lot of ingenuity and luck to successfully translate a pun into another language, and in this case I think I'm out of both.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I'd only add that saying **meæ linguæ culpa** / _though my tongue's fault_ in Latin is not too far from the OP's intended meaning, and could still be in line with the original purpose (i.e., a title and an irony, admitting blame to some extent... perhaps prioritizing close reference to a well-known aphorism?).

Comment: @Rafael The thing is, I understood the OP to be referring to written speech, and in that case "tongue" sounds a bit too metaphorical, certainly to us who clearly distingish written and oral speech.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I don't see a tongue being at all overly metaphorical. I agree with Rafael, whether it's about written or spoken language.

Comment: @cmw Not in *mea lingua,* because it refers to the tongue organ which is a synedoche (part-whole) for the actual culprit - the speaker and their neurological-articulatory state, which "culminates" in the tongue; language is not in a part-whole relationship with the speaker, has no agency, and cannot be assigned blame other than in personifying contexts (Marriage of Philology and Mercury). *lingua* "language" refers to the system of communication; *mea lingua* cannot mean "my <faulty> neurological-articulatory state", but only "my native system of communication". Hopefully I'm making sense.

Comment: So e.g. if you and @JoonasIlmavirta are thinking of an English use such as "the issue here is the language - it's too difficult" where "language" means "style", Latin *lingua* doesn't have such a use - it could only refer to an unfamiliar language. The "culmination" of speech production in the written mode of communication in Latin is the writing implement, which was prototypically *stylus.* Hence the written equivalent of the oral *meae linguae culpa* would be ***meī stylī culpa***. Which is precisely where we get "(difficult) style".—So actually, tongue is probably seen as an instrument too.

Comment: As @cmw says, the OP leaves room for interpretation. I see no obstruction for a lax understanding of "language" in use like this. Conflating written and spoken language isn't an odd or rare choice of words. // I don't understand what you mean by *lingua* only referring to an unfamiliar language.

Comment: After a discussion in chat I've elaborated on some points that Joonas raised.